# Rclone Onedrive speed up sync

Tags: sync, pop-os, rclone

I am using rclone to sync my onedrive to my computer, however the time between me changing a file on another computer and it updating in rclone is a lot slower than normal. So i was wondering if there is a command or script available that will force rclone to update my local direcory according to the changes made in the cloud. I have scoured the web and checked the rclone documentation and couldnt find anything.

I am on pop-os if that is relevant

edit: I solved the issue by adding the flag --dir-cache-time to my mount command: rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount "name":  ~/name --allow-non-empty --poll-interval 10s --dir-cache-time 15s

I also added --poll-interval at the same time so I dont know which flag gave me the desired result. cheers!

Comment: I was about to recommend you use GUI tools like Syncback and Gs Richcopy instead of Rclone, and then I see your update about how you solved the issue. great